# Re-apply for a position after being rejected

Tags: faculty-application, interview

Last year I had an interview for a position at a university. I was not good in interview and I was rejected. After obtaining experience in interviews, I was accepted for another position in another country. Now I am thinking of re-applying for that position I was rejected, ( it is still open). Given the mental background they have about my previous interview, I am confident that if I complete the application form, application will not be considered,  unless I speak to them before submitting a formal application. I want to know whether it is a logical idea to re-apply for that? Or is sending an email to the head of department and ask him to give me another opportunity? Their rejection email was polite, I mean they told me that they impressed by my CV and encouraged me for future applications, but I know that I was bad in that interview, as it was my first interview for a faculty position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sending an email to the head of department and ask him to give me another opportunity?

I do not see how that can possibly help.

> I want to know whether it is a logical idea to re-apply

If you consider that faculty jobs are difficult to get in general, no it is not logical.  But having been rejected previously might not change that situation much.  I have been interviewed in the first round twice for the same job before.

> it is still open

This is a clue something is wrong with the job.  Maybe they do not intend to fill it.  Maybe the pay is awful.  Maybe they are bad a hiring.  Maybe they posted the ad by mistake or forgot to remove it.